# Adding left and right buttons to simple image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I was wondering if anybody wanted to help completing this slider. It is ready with responsive design, what is missing is making the left and right buttons work. I have [the code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xDZPK/50/). I will post the JavaScript code at the bottom. Here is the code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider a").first().show();
        var index = 0;
        var count = 4; //Count 4 + (index) = 5 //
        function bannerRotator() {
            $('#slider a').delay(4300).eq(index).fadeOut(function () {
                if (index === count) {
                    index = -1;
                }
                $('#slider a').eq(index + 1).fadeIn(function () {
                    index++;
                    bannerRotator();
                });
            });
        }
        bannerRotator();
        $('#carousel_nav_prev').click(function () {});
    });
});
```

How can I make the slider slide left and right onclick?

Comment: Here's an old fiddle that might help.http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/hHnX5/446/

Comment: Thanks very nice....yea...I was looking at some other ones. I been learning some java but I am not so good yet... haha   :)

Comment: yea just looking for sliders.... :)

Comment: I just found one looks like I can get the .next from it and build the buttons myself       http://jsfiddle.net/EPXuH/27/